# R ggplot2 merge with shapefile and csv data to fill polygons

Tags: r, merge, ggplot2

We daily produce maps that show a calculated level for temperature in 30 distinct areas of our region, each area is filled with a different colour depending on the level. This maps look like

[image]

Now I want to switch map generation to R. I've downloaded provincial and municipal boundaries (you can find [boundaries for whole Spain](http://centrodedescargas.cnig.es/CentroDescargas/equipamiento/lineas_limite.zip) or here the [subset for my region](http://ubuntuone.com/7VMshSPgseaeJm2B7SXOz3)) and  managed to plot them with ggplot2 following Hadley's [example](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles).

I can also produce an ascii file that contains two columns: identifier (CODINE) and daily level. You can download [here](http://ubuntuone.com/6pSCvM52sz82maoLkk0n96).

This is my first script attempting to plot shapefiles with R and ggplot2 so there may be mistakes and for sure it can be improved, suggestions welcome. The following code (based on Hadley's previously mentioned) works for me:

```
> require("rgdal")
> require("maptools")
> require("ggplot2")
> require("plyr")

# Reading municipal boundaries

esp = readOGR(dsn=".", layer="lineas_limite_municipales_etrs89")

muni=subset(esp, esp$PROV1 == "46" | esp$PROV1 == "12" | esp$PROV1 == "3")
muni@data$id = rownames(muni@data)
muni.points = fortify(muni, region="id")
muni.df = join(muni.points, muni@data, by="id")

# Reading province boundaries

prov = readOGR(dsn=".", layer="poligonos_provincia_etrs89")

pr=subset(prov, prov$CODINE == "46" | prov$CODINE == "12" | prov$CODINE == "03" )
pr@data$id = rownames(pr@data)
pr.points = fortify(pr, region="id")
pr.df = join(pr.points, pr@data, by="id")

ggplot(muni.df) + aes(long,lat,group=group) + geom_path(color="blue") +
+ coord_equal()+ geom_path(data=pr.df, + 
aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group),color="red", size=0.5)
```

This code plots a nice map with all the boundaries [image]

For polygon filling by level I tried to read and then merge as suggested in http://tormodboe.wordpress.com/2011/02/22/g%C3%B8y-med-kart-2/

> level=read.csv("levels.dat",header=T,sep=" ")
>   munlevel=merge(muni.df,level,by="CODINE")

but it gives an error

> Error en fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

I am not familiar with shapefiles, maybe I need to learn more on shp data attributes to find the  right choice to merge both data sets. How can I merge data so I can plot the lines (municipal boundaries) and then fill it with levels?

Comment: An update of this question with some extra features on the map can be found at [http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/131741/9227]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[NB: This question was asked over a month ago so OP has probably found a different way to solve their problem. I stumbled upon it while working on [this related question](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/20378403/). This answer is included in hopes it will benefit someone else.]

This appears to be what OP is asking for...

[image]

... and was produced with the following code:

```
require("rgdal")
require("maptools")
require("ggplot2")
require("plyr")

# read temperature data
setwd("<location if your data file>")
temp.data        <- read.csv(file = "levels.dat", header=TRUE, sep=" ", na.string="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
temp.data$CODINE <- str_pad(temp.data$CODINE, width = 5, side = 'left', pad = '0')

# read municipality polygons
setwd("<location of your shapefile")
esp     <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="poligonos_municipio_etrs89")
muni    <- subset(esp, esp$PROVINCIA == "46" | esp$PROVINCIA == "12" | esp$PROVINCIA == "3")
# fortify and merge: muni.df is used in ggplot
muni@data$id <- rownames(muni@data)
muni.df <- fortify(muni)
muni.df <- join(muni.df, muni@data, by="id")
muni.df <- merge(muni.df, temp.data, by.x="CODIGOINE", by.y="CODINE", all.x=T, a..ly=F)
# create the map layers
ggp <- ggplot(data=muni.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group)) 
ggp <- ggp + geom_polygon(aes(fill=LEVEL))         # draw polygons
ggp <- ggp + geom_path(color="grey", linestyle=2)  # draw boundaries
ggp <- ggp + coord_equal() 
ggp <- ggp + scale_fill_gradient(low = "#ffffcc", high = "#ff4444", 
                                 space = "Lab", na.value = "grey50",
                                 guide = "colourbar")
ggp <- ggp + labs(title="Temperature Levels: Comunitat Valenciana")
# render the map
print(ggp)
```

**Explanation:**

Shapefiles imported into R with `readOGR(...)` are of type `SpacialDataFrame` and  have two main sections: a *ploygon* section which contains the coordinates of all the points on each polygon, and a *data* section which contains information about each polygon (so, one row per polygon). These can be referenced, e.g., using `muni@polygons` and `muni@data`. The utility function `fortify(...)` converts the polygon section to a data frame organized for plotting with `ggplot`. So the basic workflow is:

```
[1] Import temperature data file (temp.data)
[2] Import polygon shapefile of municipalities (muni)
[3] Convert muni polygons to a data frame for plotting (muni.df <- fortify(...))
[4] Join columns from muni@data to muni.df
[5] Join columns from temp.data to muni.df
[6] Make the plot
```

The joins must be done on common fields, and this is where most of the problems come in. Each polygon in the original shapefile has a unique ID attribute. Running `fortify(...)` on the shapefile creates a column, `id`, which is based on this. But there is no ID column in the data section. Instead, the polygon IDs are stored as row names. So first we must add an `id` column to `muni@data` as follows:

```
muni@data$id <- rownames(muni@data)
```

Now we have an `id` field in `muni@data` and a corresponding `id` field in `muni.df`, so we can do the join:

```
muni.df <- join(muni.df, muni@data, by="id")
```

To create the map we will need to set fill colors based on temperature level. To do that we need to join the `LEVEL` column from `temp.data` to `muni.df`. In `temp.data` there is a field `CODINE` which identifies the municipality. There is also, now, a corresponding field `CODIGOINE` in `muni.df`. But there's a problem: `CODIGOINE` is `char(5)`, with leading zeros, whereas `CODINE` is integer which means leading zeros are missing (imported from Excel, perhaps?). So just joining on these two fields produces no matches. We must first convert `CODINE` into `char(5)` with leading zeros:

```
temp.data$CODINE <- str_pad(temp.data$CODINE, width = 5, side = 'left', pad = '0')
```

Now we can join `temp.dat` to `muni.df` based on the corresponding fields.

```
muni.df <- merge(muni.df, temp.data, by.x="CODIGOINE", by.y="CODINE", all.x=T, a..ly=F)
```

We use `merge(...)` instead of `join(...)` because the join fields have different names and `join(...)` requires them to have the same name. (Note, however that `join(...)` is faster and should be used if possible). So, finally, we have a data frame which contains all the information for plotting the polygons and the temperature `LEVEL` which can be used to establish the fill color for each polygon.

Some notes on OP's original code:

1. OP's first map (the green one at the top) identifies "30 distinct areas for our region...". I could find no shapefile identifying those areas. The municipality file identifies 543 municipalities, and I could see no way to group these into 30 areas. In addition, the temperature level file has 542 rows, one for each municipality (more or less).
2. OP was importing line shapefiles for municipality to draw the boundaries. You don't need that because `geom_polygon(...)` will draw (and fill) the polygons and `geom_path(...)` will draw the boundaries.

Comment: Hi, I didn't find a solution but I'm gonna try your code. Your map looks impressive and exactly what I wanted. I had to leave the question for a time as I had another problems to solve before. Thank you very much for your hard work.

Comment: If this works for you please consider selecting as the answer (green checkmark).

Comment: I had some problem with your script because of my shapefile. I downloaded again and now the code runs perfect for my needs. Great job @jlhoward

Comment: I had to do it a bit differently. With `fortify(muni, region = 'id')` (otherwise it does not use `id` variable) and  with `merge` (I guess, a different version of `dplyr`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052544/convert-map-data-to-data-frame-using-fortify-ggplot2-for-spatial-objects-in-r

Comment: If `merge` is slow, you could use `dplyr` and use `left_join(muni.df,temp.data,by=c("CODIGOINE"="CODINE")) which is equivalent to `merge(x,y,all.x=TRUE,all.y=FALSE)`

Comment: @jlhoward thank you for your answer, I found it helpful in 2024! I'll appreciate your help on something similar:  I need code to replace muni@data$id <- rownames(muni@data), because maptools and rgdal are now deprecated.  Thank you. I shared my question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78107699/import-shapefile-and-join-to-coordinates-to-create-spatial-dataframe-in-r