# How to add legend for regional map with a legend describing associated labels using ggplot2?

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

SpatialPoly Data: [SpatialData](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4x7kkragmnl6tkk/Morocco_adm1.zip)

Yield Data: [Yield Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rzlfuqxwzkqwgbg/Morocco_Yield.csv)

Code:

```
    ## Loading packages
    library(rgdal)
    library(plyr)
    library(maps)
    library(maptools)
    library(mapdata)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(RColorBrewer)
    library(foreign)  
    library(sp)

    ## Loading shapefiles and .csv files
    #Morocco <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="Morocco_adm0")
    MoroccoReg <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="Morocco_adm1")
    MoroccoYield <- read.csv(file = "F:/Purdue University/RA_Position/PhD_ResearchandDissert/PhD_Draft/Country-CGE/RMaps_Morocco/Morocco_Yield.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.string="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)

    ## Reorder the data in the shapefile based on the category variable "ID_1" and change to dataframe
    MoroccoReg <- MoroccoReg[order(MoroccoReg$ID_1), ]
    MoroccoReg.df <- fortify(MoroccoReg)

    ## Add the yield impacts column to shapefile from the .csv file by "ID_1"
    ## Note that in the .csv file, I just added the column "ID_1" to match it with the shapefile
    MoroccoReg.df <- cbind(MoroccoReg.df,MoroccoYield,by = 'ID_1')

    ## Check the structure and contents of shapefile
    attributes(MoroccoReg.df)

    ## Define new theme for map
    ## I have found this function on the website
    theme_map <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
    theme_gray(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
    theme(
    axis.line=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.length=unit(0.3, "lines"),
    axis.ticks.margin=unit(0.5, "lines"),
    axis.title.x=element_blank(),
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    legend.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour=NA),
    legend.key=element_rect(colour="white"),
    legend.key.size=unit(1.5, "lines"),
    legend.position="right",
    legend.text=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
    legend.title=element_text(size=rel(1.4), face="bold", hjust=0),
    panel.background=element_blank(),
    panel.border=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
    panel.margin=unit(0, "lines"),
    plot.background=element_blank(),
    plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"),
    plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.8), face="bold", hjust=0.5),
    strip.background=element_rect(fill="grey90", colour="grey50"),
    strip.text.x=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),
    strip.text.y=element_text(size=rel(0.8), angle=-90) 
    )   
    }

    ## Plotting 

    MoroccoRegMap1 <- ggplot(data = MoroccoReg.df, aes(long, lat, group = group)) 
    MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = A2Med_noCO2))
    MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
    #MoroccoRegMap <- MoroccoRegMap + scale_fill_gradient(low = "#CC0000",high = "#006600")
    MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + scale_fill_gradient2(name = "%Change in yield",low = "#CC0000",mid = "#FFFFFF",high = "#006600")
    MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + labs(title="SRES_A2, noCO2 Effect")
    MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + coord_equal() + theme_map()
    MoroccoRegMap1
```

Results:

[image: Map]

Question:

In Yield data, I have a column that describes the labels corresponding to each of the entries in the column "ID_1". What I am trying to achieve is two things:

1) plot the map and add the "ID_1" variable entries as labels on the map, thus identifying each region;

2) generate a second legend, besides the one that captures the values in the data, and which the entries in "ID_1" and their corresponding description in the "Labels" column in the dataframe.

I hope I framed my question clearly.

thanks.

Comment: So I downloaded your polygon data and was unable to read it, in R or in QGIS 2.0.1. Are you sure the file is not corrupted??

Comment: @jlhoward: I am pretty sure it is working. I double checked and I was able to load the file in R and perform all the other operation where I transform it to a data frame in order to merge it with the yield data. And I was able to reproduce the same map as above.

Comment: @smailov63 - I'm sure your original file is fine, but did you re-download your uploaded file? Sometimes they become corrupted during upload.

Comment: @jlhoward - I re-uploaded the polygon data file just to make sure. Truth be told, I did not run the code using the file as initially uploaded here since I have already in project directory. So perhaps you are right that something went wrong when I did upload it. Let me know if the re-uploading solved the issue. Thanks

Comment: @smailov63 - So the problem with the upload is this: a "shapefile" is not one file, but a set of files, including `.shp, .prj, .dbf, .csv, .shx`. `readOGR(...)` looks for all of them. I found a Morocco administrative area shapefile [here](http://www.gadm.org/country), but your code does not run when I use that. Could you upload all of the `Morocco_adm1.*` files?

Comment: @jlhoward - I just updated the spatial data. I uploaded a zip file that contains the .shp, .dbf, and .shx files to plot the polygons. I hope this solves the issue. The .csv file contains only the yield data that I merge with the spatial data after transforming it into a dataframe as is done in the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, let me apologize for taking so long to get back - I missed your comment among all the others. Is this what you had in mind?

[image]

This was produced with the following code. Before getting into an explanation, you should be aware that creating a legend is the least of your problems. Note how the colors are different in the two maps. Your code above does not assign CO2 changes to the correct regions. For example, according to `MoroccoYields.csv`, the largest change (improvement?) was `-0.205` in `Region 4`, but on your map the largest (darkest red) is at the northeastern tip of Morocco, which is actually `l'Oriental (Region 6)`. An explanation follows the code.

```
## Loading packages
library(rgdal)
library(plyr)
library(maps)
library(maptools)
library(mapdata)
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(foreign)  
library(sp)

# get.centroids: function to extract polygon ID and centroid from shapefile
get.centroids = function(x){
  poly = MoroccoReg@polygons[[x]]
  ID   = poly@ID
  centroid = as.numeric(poly@labpt)
  return(c(id=ID, long=centroid[1], lat=centroid[2]))
}
#setwd("Directory where shapefile and Yields are stored")
## Loading shapefiles and .csv files
MoroccoReg        <- readOGR(dsn=".", layer="Morocco_adm1")
MoroccoYield      <- read.csv(file = "Morocco_Yield.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",", na.string="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
MoroccoYield$ID_1 <- substr(MoroccoYield$ID_1,3,10)

## Reorder the data in the shapefile based on the category variable "ID_1" and change to dataframe
MoroccoReg    <- MoroccoReg[order(MoroccoReg$ID_1), ]
MoroccoYield  <- cbind(id=rownames(MoroccoReg@data),MoroccoYield)
#  build table of labels for annotation (legend).
labs          <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:14,get.centroids))
labs          <- merge(labs,MoroccoYield[,c("id","ID_1","Label")],by="id")
labs[,2:3]    <- sapply(labs[,2:3],function(x){as.numeric(as.character(x))})
labs$sort <- as.numeric(as.character(labs$ID_1))
labs          <- labs[order(labs$sort),]

MoroccoReg.df <- fortify(MoroccoReg)
## This does NOT work...
## Add the yield impacts column to shapefile from the .csv file by "ID_1"
## Note that in the .csv file, I just added the column "ID_1" to match it with the shapefile
#MoroccoReg.df <- cbind(MoroccoReg.df,MoroccoYield,by = 'ID_1')
## Do it this way...
MoroccoReg.df <- merge(MoroccoReg.df,MoroccoYield, by="id")

## Check the structure and contents of shapefile
attributes(MoroccoReg.df)
## Plotting 

MoroccoRegMap1 <- ggplot(data = MoroccoReg.df, aes(long, lat, group=id)) 
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = A2Med_noCO2))
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + scale_fill_gradient2(name = "%Change in yield",low = "#CC0000",mid = "#FFFFFF",high = "#006600")
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + labs(title="SRES_A2, noCO2 Effect")
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + coord_equal() #+ theme_map()
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_text(data=labs, aes(x=long, y=lat, label=ID_1), size=4)
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + annotate("text", x=max(labs$long)-5, y=min(labs$lat)+3-0.5*(1:14),
                                            label=paste(labs$ID_1,": ",labs$Label,sep=""),
                                            size=3, hjust=0)
MoroccoRegMap1
```

**Explanation:**

First, on merging your yield data with the map regions: you use

```
MoroccoReg.df <- cbind(MoroccoReg.df,MoroccoYield,by = 'ID_1')
```

This is not how `cbind(...)` works. `cbind(...)` merely combines it's arguments column-wise. It is not a merge function. So you had a data frame, `MoroccoReg.df`, with 107,800 rows (one row for every line endpoint on your map), and you are combining it with `MoroccoYield`, which has 14 rows (1 for every Region). So `cbind(...)` replicates those 14 rows 7700 times to fill out the 107,800 rows it needs. The expression `by="ID_1"` merely adds another column named "`by"` with `"ID_1"` replicated 107,800 times. Run the statement above and type `head(MoroccoReg.df)` and look for the last column.

So how to do the merge? There are a number of functions in `R` that are supposed to make this easy, but I couldn't get any of them to work. This is what did work:

Every polygon in the shapefile has an ID. There is also an "ID_1" field in the shapefile data section, but these are *different and unrelated*. [BTW: The `ID_1` field in the shapefile data section, and the `ID_1` field in your `csv` file were also different: the latter has `"TR"` prepended to the region number; so that had to be dealt with as well].
Reordering the shapefile with:

```
MoroccoReg    <- MoroccoReg[order(MoroccoReg$ID_1), ]
```

will change the order of the polygons, but will not change their ID's. It turns out that the polygon ID matches the row name in the data section of the shapefile, so I prepended that (using `cbind(...)`!) to your `MoroccoYeild` data frame.

```
MoroccoYield  <- cbind(id=rownames(MoroccoReg@data),MoroccoYield)
```

So now `MoroccoYield` has an `id` field which maps to the polygon ID, and an `ID_1` field, which identifies the Region. Now we can `fortify(...)` and `merge(...)`. `merge(...)` does take a `by=` argument.

```
MoroccoReg.df <- fortify(MoroccoReg)
MoroccoReg.df <- merge(MoroccoReg.df,MoroccoYield, by="id")
```

This appends all of your `MoroccoYield` columns to the appropriate rows of `MoroccoReg.df`.

Creating the legend:

The obvious question is how to position the labels? Ideally, we would place the Region number from `MoroccoYield$ID_1` at the centroid of each region, and then create a legend that identifies the Regions, based on `MoroccoYield$Label`.

So where to find the centroids? These are stored in an obscure location in the polygon section of the shapefile. To make a long story short, I created a utility function `get.centroid(...)` which extracts the centroid from a polygon. Then I applied that function to all the polygons to produce a table of centroids with corresponding polygon ID. Then I merged that with the labels in `MoroccoYield`. This created a data frame `labs` which has the following columns:

```
id:    polygon ID
long:  centroid longitude
lat:   centroid latitude
ID_1:  region ID
label: region name
sort:  a sortable (numeric) version of ID_1
```

Then, adding the following code to your ggplot...

```
...
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_text(data=labs, aes(x=long, y=lat, label=label.id), size=4)
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + annotate("text", x=max(labs$long)-5, y=min(labs$lat)+3-0.5*(1:14),
                                            label=paste(labs$label.id,": ",labs$Label,sep=""),
                                            size=3, hjust=0)
```

...creates the map. There's no clean way, that I could find, to do this with a formal "ggplot legend", so I had to use `annotate(...)`. Positioning the annotation is kind of a hack, but it seems to work.

**Edit:** In response to @smailov83's comment, if you change the code to create the ggplot to this...

```
MoroccoRegMap1 <- ggplot(data = MoroccoReg.df, aes(long, lat, group=group)) 
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_polygon(aes(fill = A2Med_noCO2))
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_path(colour = 'gray', linestyle = 2)
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + scale_fill_gradient2(name = "%Change in yield",low = "#CC0000",mid = "#FFFFFF",high = "#006600")
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + labs(title="SRES_A2, noCO2 Effect")
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + coord_equal() #+ theme_map()
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + geom_text(data=labs, aes(x=long, y=lat, label=ID_1, group=ID_1), size=4)
MoroccoRegMap1 <- MoroccoRegMap1 + annotate("text", x=max(labs$long)-5, y=min(labs$lat)+3-0.5*(1:14),
                                            label=paste(labs$ID_1,": ",labs$Label,sep=""),
                                            size=3, hjust=0)
```

...you get this:

[image]

Which I believe fixes the problem. The reason for the extra lines in your map was that the `ggplot` must be grouped by the column `MoroccoReg.df$group` (so, `aes(..., group=group)` *not* `aes(...,group=id)`). When you do this, however, `ggplot` tries to group by `"group"` in all layers. In `geom_text(...)`, where we are using a new, local dataset - the `labs` data frame - there is no `group` column. To deal with this, we must explicitly set `group` to something else in `geom_text(...)`. Bottom line: this seem to work.

Comment: no apologies needed, and in fact I am the one who should since I have been providing an incomplete data from the get go. And this is what I had in mind, if not more :)
I do though have a remark. So when you check your version of the map that you plotted with the modified code, I see that there are some discrepancies on it, like some straight lines cutting crossing multiple regions (e.g. a line going right through region 2 and other couple ones). So is that a fixable problem? What do you think causes that?