# Making a specific legend in R ggplot: manually assigning colors and values polygons should take

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, legend

I am currently trying to make a map that 1) labels every polygon with their respective name and 2) gives every polygon a specific color based on the number of counts it has.

Reading several Stack overflow posts I found one that really helped me out a lot ([Labeling center of map polygons in R ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038640/labeling-center-of-map-polygons-in-r-ggplot)), but I am encountering two main problems: 1) I can't seem to specify the specific colors I want the map to take, and 2) I can't seem to get the legend just the way I want it to be.

I am going to use code given by user Silverfish in the post ([Labeling center of map polygons in R ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038640/labeling-center-of-map-polygons-in-r-ggplot)) I previously mentioned:

```
library(rgdal) # used to read world map data
library(rgeos) # to fortify without needing gpclib
library(maptools)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales) # for formatting ggplot scales with commas

#Data from http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php.
#Direct link: http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3.zip
#Unpack and put the files in a dir 'data'

worldMap <- readOGR(dsn="data", layer="TM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3")
# Change "data" to your path in the above!
worldMap.fort <- fortify(worldMap, region = "ISO3")
# Fortifying a map makes the data frame ggplot uses to draw the map outlines.
# "region" or "id" identifies those polygons, and links them to your data. 
# Look at head(worldMap@data) to see other choices for id.
# Your data frame needs a column with matching ids to set as the map_id aesthetic in ggplot. 
idList <- worldMap@data$ISO3
# "coordinates" extracts centroids of the polygons, in the order listed at worldMap@data
centroids.df <- as.data.frame(coordinates(worldMap))
names(centroids.df) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")  #more sensible column names
# This shapefile contained population data, let's plot it.
popList <- worldMap@data$POP2005

pop.df <- data.frame(id = idList, population = popList, centroids.df)

ggplot(pop.df, aes(map_id = id)) + #"id" is col in your df, not in the map object 
  geom_map(aes(fill = population), colour= "grey", map = worldMap.fort) +
  expand_limits(x = worldMap.fort$long, y = worldMap.fort$lat) +
  scale_fill_gradient(high = "red", low = "white", guide = "colorbar", labels = comma) +
  geom_text(aes(label = id, x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) + #add labels at centroids
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-90,-30), ylim = c(-60, 20)) + #let's view South America
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", title = "World Population") +
  theme_bw()
```

[This is what the code currently outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B5BU.jpg)

This example allowed me to learn how to place labels on the polygons in a map, but I needed to do several changes before I got where I needed to be:
1) I need the scale to not be a gradient, but in the form of a legend giving a color for a specific range of values. The color and range I want are the following (colors are specified in HEX form):
- Range: 0        Color: "White"
- Range: 1-99     Color: "#d3c874"
- Range: 100-249  Color: "#d69b26"
- Range: 250-499  Color: "#89280d"
- Range: 500+     Color: "#411614"

2) I need the legend to appear on the bottom and go from left to right

3) I need the Polygons to take their correct colors based on their counts

In the 'pop.df' data frame I created another column (Categ), assigning the values "1", "2", "3", "4", or "5" based on the ranges I previously mentioned:
- Range: 0        Value: "1"
- Range: 1-99     Value: "2"
- Range: 100-249  Value: "3"
- Range: 250-499  Value: "4"
- Range: 500+     Value: "5"
(NOTE: seeing that the counts used in this example are very large numbers I am aware that every single polygon will most likely be above 500+, these are just the ranges I am using my own purposes).

I did this so it would be easier to assign a color to a polygon when plotting the map. Basically, I thought it would be easier this way than to create code that first checked the count, compared it to a range, and then gave a color. I will clarify it doesn't need to be done this way, I am just saying the way I have approached it.

I used this code to make that happen:

```
Pop.df$Categ <- ifelse(Pop.df$population < 1, "1",
                             ifelse(Pop.df$population >= 1 & Pop.df$population < 100, "2", 
                                    ifelse(Pop.df$population >= 100 & Pop.df$population < 250, "3", 
                                           ifelse(Pop.df$population >= 250 & Pop.df$population < 500, "4", "5"))))
```

Seeing that the colors I need are not part of a specific palette, and that I need those specific colors in the map, I started to use the 'scale_colour_manual' instead of the 'scale_fill_gradient' approach to tweak the legend as I need, but it doesn't seem to be working. The specific obstacles I am facing are:
a) I cant seem to make the legend be from a gradient to discrete values
b) The colors that some up in the map are nothing like the colors I need. I don't know if it's because of the HEX code or something else.

I have approached this in several ways. The most recent code I have used is this one:

```
ggplot(pop.df, aes(map_id = id)) +
geom_map(aes(fill = population), colour= "black", map
= worldMap.fort) +
expand_limits(x = worldMap.fort$long, y = worldMap.fort$lat) + 
scale_colour_manual(values = c("white", "#d3c874", "#d69b26", "#89280d", "#411614"), 
                      limits = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), breaks = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")) + #This is my attempts to getting the legend to work
geom_text(aes(label = id, x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) + #add labels at centroids
coord_equal(xlim = c(-90,-30), ylim = c(-60, 20)) + #let's view South America
labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", title = "World Population") +
theme_bw()
```

With regards to the position of the legend, I haven't even started to tackle that issue seeing I am first trying to make it display properly.

Any insight would be amazing guys! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ultimately, you needed to supply the `fill` aesthetic with your discrete Categ variable, instead of the continuous population variable. Then use `scale_fill_manual()` because you want to fill the countries with a color (not color their borders), and you're already coloring the borders black in `geom_map()`. See the code with comments below.

```
# same code as in your question, 
# but (1) changed population categories (added four zeroes) so that
# more countries fall in different bins, 
# (just so I could see if my subsequent solutions worked)
# and (2) used the hex colors you supplied as category values, rather than 1-5
pop.df$Categ <- ifelse(pop.df$population < 1, "#ffffff",
                   ifelse(pop.df$population >= 1 & pop.df$population < 1000000, "#d3c874", 
                          ifelse(pop.df$population >= 1000000 & pop.df$population < 2500000, "#d69b26", 
                                 ifelse(pop.df$population >= 2500000 & pop.df$population < 5000000, "#89280d", "#411614"))))
# convert Categ to factor
pop.df$Categ <- factor(pop.df$Categ, levels = c("#ffffff", "#d3c874", "#d69b26", "#89280d", "#411614"))
# plot
ggplot(pop.df, aes(map_id = id)) +
  geom_map(aes(fill=Categ), colour= "black", map = worldMap.fort) +
  expand_limits(x = worldMap.fort$long, y = worldMap.fort$lat) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ffffff", "#d3c874", "#d69b26", "#89280d", "#411614"), 
              breaks = c("#ffffff", "#d3c874", "#d69b26", "#89280d", "#411614"), 
              labels = c("zero", "< 1 million", "1 to 2.5 million", "2.5 to 5 million", "> 5 million")) 
  geom_text(aes(label = id, x = Longitude, y = Latitude)) + #add labels at centroids
  coord_equal(xlim = c(-90,-30), ylim = c(-60, 20)) + #let's view South America
  labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", title = "World Population") +
  theme_bw()
```

(I understand that you have your reasons for specifying your population categories. I just changed them so that I could more easily see whether or not what I was doing was working.)

That code should return the following plot:

[image]

You can then change the position of the legend by adding `+ theme(legend.position = ...)`, where the acceptable values are "top", "bottom", "left", "right", "none", or a zero-to-one coordinate system (for example, c(0.5, 0.5) would put your legend right in the middle of your plot).

so, adding `+ theme(legend.position = c(0.83, 0.857), legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent",colour=NA))` to your ggplot object would yield:

[image]

Comment: The code works perfectly, Thank you so much!
I wanted to see if I could ask some follow up questions in order to understand the code and not really be using things I don't understand:
1) In the `scale_fill_manual`: is it correct to say that `breaks` and `values` work together to identify what color is give to each polygon?
2) if so, then what is the `limits` option used for within the `scale_fill_manual` context?

Comment: `breaks` specifies the order of your category values as appearing in the legend, but `limits` specifies which category values get which colors (though I've personally never had a case where the order of values needs to be different than the order displayed in the legend). So, if you specified `limits=c("3","1","2","4","5")` then category value "3" would get the first color specified under `values`. See the last three examples at http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/scale_manual.html