# geom_text - finding centroids and adding text in a polygon using ggplot2 -

Tags: r, ggplot2, centroid, geom-text

I would like to create a label text layer on a polygon map. 
This is a very similar query from the two below :

[Labeling center of map polygons in R ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038640/labeling-center-of-map-polygons-in-r-ggplot)

[ggplot centered names on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441436/ggplot-centered-names-on-a-map)

My dataframe is as follows, (I simplified long and lat for clarity - they are coordinates)

```
id  long   lat   order  hole    piece  group   locid   location

0   long1  lat1  1      false   1      0.1     1       TEXT I WANT
0   long2  lat2  2      false   1      0.1     1       TEXT I WANT
1   long3  lat3  3      false   1      1.1     2       TEXT I WANT2
1   long4  lat4  4      false   1      1.1     2       TEXT I WANT2
```

This is my current code, it returns a black map - I assume there's text for every long and lat coordinates. 
I am struggling to find the centroids of each polygon so that i can add a text layer only as per the polygone centre.

```
testtext <- ggplot() +
           geom_polygon(data = df, mapping = aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, fill=location)) +
           geom_text(data = df, mapping = aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, label=location)) +
           geom_path(color = "white") +
           scale_fill_hue(l=40) +
           coord_equal() +
           theme(legend.position = "none", title = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank())
```

Many thanks

Comment: Please make your example [_reproducible_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: thanks for the link, will edit - that being said, it will be complicated to add some coordinates as I have numerous polygons, hence observations in my df.

Comment: `coordinates()` will give you centroids of polygons if you have a proper `sp` object.

Answer (score 2):

[Andrie's asnwer on ggplot centered names on a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441436/ggplot-centered-names-on-a-map)

Based on Andrie's input in the above link, I created a new vector with `aggregate()` that does the trick - although centering text within a polygon using  means of coordinates is debatable. Will look into `coordinates()` @Roman Luštrik

```
library(ggplot2)
centroid <- aggregate(cbind(long,lat) ~ location, data=df, FUN=mean)
testtext <- ggplot() +
            geom_polygon(data = df, mapping = aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, fill=location)) +
            geom_text(data = centroid, mapping = aes(x=long, y=lat, label=location)) +
            geom_path(color = "white") +
            scale_fill_hue(l=40) +
            coord_equal() +
            theme(legend.position = "none", title = element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank())
```