# How to put value labels inside polygons and not on their edges in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, polygon

In R, I have hexbins / tilegrams representing jurisdictions of a Canadian province, but the ID labels of hexbins are sitting on the polygons' corners, not inside them.

The closest I got to the desired chart:

[image]

I have been messing with `geom_polygon`, `geom_text` and `geom_label` and a few others, but nothing will do. I have seen people use `rgeos` for doing this with US statebins but I am guessing this is not necessary in my case, as R does recognise that my hexbins have some ID attached to them, it's just placing them not where I want them. I also tried changing the position argument within geoms.

```
tileGram_f <- ggplot2::fortify(tileGram2) 
tileGram_f <- plyr::join(tileGram_f, tileGram2@data[,c("id", "tile_region")],by="id")

names(tileGram_f)[names(tileGram_f)=="tile_region"] <- "Country"

ggplot(tileGram_f) +
  geom_polygon(aes(long, lat, group = group), 
               fill = "yellow", color = "blue", show.legend = FALSE, size = 1) + 
  coord_equal() + 
  geom_text(data = tileGram_f, 
            aes(x = long, y = lat, label = Country),
            size = 8, color = "red", check_overlap = TRUE) +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.title = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank())
```

The hexbins' IDs are made visible by `geom_text()` or `geom_label()` successfully (ID numbers, 0-21), but they are placed on each of a polygon / hexbin corner. I want them only ONCE per hexbin and inside it, not around it.

Comment: It seems that you might need to finding the coordinates of each center of the poligons and use those for your geom_text

Comment: If `tileGram2` is a spatial object, finding a centroid may not be that difficult.

Comment: Been able to find the centroids / coordinates, both ways below worked, but I have yet to combine those centroids with ggplot2 as it keeps telling me that it must be of length 1 or 21.

`# from rgeos - this below 

trueCentroids = gCentroid(tileGram2,byid=TRUE)
plot(tileGram2)
points(coordinates(tileGram2),pch=1)
points(trueCentroids,pch=2)

trueCentroids
trueCentroidsDF <- as.data.frame(trueCentroids)

# or maybe with coordinates() ?

trueCoordinates <- coordinates(tileGram2)
colnames(trueCoordinates) <- c('x', 'y')
trueCoordinates <- as.data.frame(trueCoordinates)`

Comment: Ok I've got help from the most popular answer in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038640/labeling-center-of-map-polygons-in-r-ggplot). In `geom_text`, my `label` argument was `names(trueCoordinates)`, but it was giving me this length error above. My error was to use `names()` instead or `rownames()` ... oops! I have my desired chart now, thanks for the leads guys !

Comment: For reference, code amendment, finding coordinates :
`trueCoordinates <- coordinates(tileGram2)
colnames(trueCoordinates) <- c('x', 'y')
trueCoordinates <- as.data.frame(trueCoordinates)

trueCoordinates$id = rownames(trueCoordinates)`
geom_text resolution :
`geom_text(data = trueCoordinates, aes(x = x, y = y, label = rownames(trueCoordinates)))`

Comment: @EvetsLefurac If you have additional information you'd like to clarify, please edit that into your question. If you have solved your problem, you can pose that as an answer and accept it (after a number of hours, I think). Long code chunks in comments are hard to read, at the best of times.