# Using geom_text() to display text in geom_polygon()

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, geom-text

I am trying to add geom_text layer on top of geom_polygon in order to display each polygon's label. Without geom_text, it produces a plot as shown below:

[image: geom_polygon output]

I want it to have texts on each polygon that looks something like this:

[image: text polygon]

Here is what my data M looks like:

[image: M data]

I created a new data frame called county_text_df because using M data for geom_text would consume too much memory. Here's what the data county_text_df and M looks like:

```
structure(list(county = c("종로구", "중구", "용산구", "성동구", 
"광진구", "동대문구", "중랑구", "성북구", "강북구", "도봉구", 
"노원구", "은평구", "서대문구", "마포구", "양천구", "강서구", 
"구로구", "금천구", "영등포구", "동작구", "관악구", "서초구", 
"강남구", "송파구", "강동구"), lat = c(37.5990998, 37.5579452, 
37.5311008, 37.5506753, 37.5481445, 37.5838012, 37.5953795, 37.606991, 
37.6469954, 37.6658609, 37.655264, 37.6176125, 37.5820369, 37.5622906, 
37.5270616, 37.5657617, 37.4954856, 37.4600969, 37.520641, 37.4965037, 
37.4653993, 37.4769528, 37.4959854, 37.5048534, 37.5492077), 
    long = c(126.9861493, 126.9941904, 126.9810742, 127.0409622, 
    127.0857528, 127.0507003, 127.0939669, 127.0232185, 127.0147158, 
    127.0317674, 127.0771201, 126.9227004, 126.9356665, 126.9087803, 
    126.8561534, 126.8226561, 126.858121, 126.9001546, 126.9139242, 
    126.9443073, 126.9438071, 127.0378103, 127.0664091, 127.1144822, 
    127.1464824)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L
))
```

Here is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(maptools)
library(rgeos) # rgeos version: 0.5-5, (SVN revision 640)
library(ggplot2)
county_text_df<- data.frame(county = unique(M$county), 
                            lat = unique(M$lat.y), 
                            long = unique(M$long.y))
county_text_df %>% head()

ggplot() + 
  geom_polygon(data = M, 
               aes(x = long.x, 
                   y = lat.x, 
                   group = group, 
                   fill = cnt), 
               color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "#FBCF61", 
                      high = "#00CC99", 
                      space = "Lab", 
                      guide = "colourbar") +
  geom_text(data = county_text_df,
            mapping = aes(x = long,
                          y = lat,
                          label = county,
                          size = 4,
                          colour = "blue"))
```

I would greatly appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Please make your code [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Your `dput` does not contain `lat.y`, `long.y`, `group`, `cnt`.

Comment: what is exactly the problem?

Comment: @tjebo I want to display names for each polygon.

Comment: @BappaDas I am unable to post the reproducible data because it's too big. Even taking a sample of a row for each county exceeds the limit.

Comment: @tjebo I've added an image that is similar to what I want to produce.

Comment: I am still not sure what the problem is - you have the coordinates for the labels and the polygons right? What's not working with your code? do the following threads help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22038640/labeling-center-of-map-polygons-in-r-ggplot and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9441436/ggplot-centered-names-on-a-map