# How keep information from shapefile after fortify()

Tags: r, ggplot2, rgdal

How can I keep polygons's information after shapefile? Let me try to explain:

I have a shapefile with this data:

```
> head(mapa@data)
         ID      CD_GEOCODI   TIPO   CD_GEOCODB    NM_BAIRRO  CD_GEOCODS NM_SUBDIST CD_GEOCODD   NM_DISTRIT CD_GEOCODM   NM_MUNICIP     NM_MICRO                       NM_MESO
12228 33679 431490205000133 URBANO 431490205003 Cidade Baixa 43149020500       <NA>  431490205 PORTO ALEGRE    4314902 PORTO ALEGRE PORTO ALEGRE METROPOLITANA DE PORTO ALEGRE
12229 33680 431490205000134 URBANO 431490205003 Cidade Baixa 43149020500       <NA>  431490205 PORTO ALEGRE    4314902 PORTO ALEGRE PORTO ALEGRE METROPOLITANA DE PORTO ALEGRE
12230 33681 431490205000135 URBANO 431490205003 Cidade Baixa 43149020500       <NA>  431490205 PORTO ALEGRE    4314902 PORTO ALEGRE PORTO ALEGRE METROPOLITANA DE PORTO ALEGRE
12231 33682 431490205000136 URBANO 431490205003 Cidade Baixa 43149020500       <NA>  431490205 PORTO ALEGRE    4314902 PORTO ALEGRE PORTO ALEGRE METROPOLITANA DE PORTO ALEGRE
12232 33683 431490205000137 URBANO 431490205003 Cidade Baixa 43149020500       <NA>  431490205 PORTO ALEGRE    4314902 PORTO ALEGRE PORTO ALEGRE METROPOLITANA DE PORTO ALEGRE
12233 33684 431490205000138 URBANO 431490205003 Cidade Baixa 43149020500       <NA>  431490205 PORTO ALEGRE    4314902 PORTO ALEGRE PORTO ALEGRE METROPOLITANA DE PORTO ALEGRE
```

and this data:

```
> head(data)
       CD_GEOCODI Population
1 431490205000133       1272
2 431490205000134        822
3 431490205000135       1085
4 431490205000136       1454
5 431490205000137        964
6 431490205000138        834
```

I could just merge `data` and `mapa@data` and plot it with `plot()`, but I want use ggplot2. But `fortify()`'s output donsn't have any of originals variables. For example:

```
> head(fortify(mapa))
Regions defined for each Polygons
       long       lat order  hole piece   group    id
1 -51.22254 -30.03526     1 FALSE     1 12228.1 12228
2 -51.22332 -30.03648     2 FALSE     1 12228.1 12228
3 -51.22365 -30.03702     3 FALSE     1 12228.1 12228
4 -51.22482 -30.03610     4 FALSE     1 12228.1 12228
5 -51.22488 -30.03606     5 FALSE     1 12228.1 12228
6 -51.22476 -30.03591     6 FALSE     1 12228.1 12228
```

Both (fortify and mapa@data) have an id variable, but aren't the same values. So, again, my question is: How can I pass `mapa@data`'s information to `fortify()`'s output (or another function that allows use ggplot2)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you did not provide your shapefile or data, it's impossible to test, but something like this should work:

```
# not tested...
library(plyr)      # for join(...)
library(rgdal)     # for readOGR(...)
library(ggplot2)   # for fortify(...)

mapa <- readOGR(dsn=".",layer="shapefile name w/o .shp extension")
map@data$id <- rownames(mapa@data)
mapa@data   <- join(mapa@data, data, by="CD_GEOCODI")
mapa.df     <- fortify(mapa)
mapa.df     <- join(mapa.df,mapa@data, by="id")

ggplot(mapa.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group))+
  geom_polygon(aes(fill=Population))+
  coord_fixed()
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't noticed that `id` values was rows's names.

Comment: I had to do it a bit differently. With `fortify(muni, region = 'id')` (otherwise it does not use `id` variable) and  with `merge` (I guess, a different version of `dplyr`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052544/convert-map-data-to-data-frame-using-fortify-ggplot2-for-spatial-objects-in-r

Comment: I have a question about the 'id' column that is generated by fortify (or broom::tidy). It starts from 0. Does it correspond to the order of spatial objects in the shapefile?

Comment: It is incorrect to do join(mapa.df,mapa@data, by="id"), as the id in mapa.df starts from 0 but the id in mapa@data starts from 1.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe this is a slightly simpler solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# fortify the shape file
  map.df <- fortify(shape, region ="CD_GEOCODI")

# merge data
  map.df <- left_join(map.df, data, by=c('id'='CD_GEOCODI'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem and was able to achieve the desired results using slightly different approach.

## Import and fortify

I have used the following code to read the shapes:

```
shps <- maptools::readShapePoly(fn = file.path("file",
                                               "path",
                                               "no extension"),
                                     # Column with unique IDs
                                     IDvar = "geoID")
```

and subsequently fortified the objet using the code:

```
shpsFort <- ggplot2::fortify(model = shps)
```

## Results

This created a [data.frame](/questions/tagged/data.frame) object with the `id` value corresponding to the column passed in `IDvar = "geoID"`. Adding any other data could be simply addressed via ordinary `merge` command.

Answer (score 1):

Assumption that data$CD_GEOCODI and shape@data are both unique for each row. Below is a better and simpler answer:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# fortify the shape file
  map.df <- fortify(shape, region ="CD_GEOCODI")

# change data$CD_GEOCODI to character, as shp.df$CD_GEOCODI is of character class.
  data <- data %>% mutate(data, CD_GEOCODI = as.character(CD_GEOCODI))

# merge data
  map.df <- left_join(map.df, data, by=c('id'='CD_GEOCODI'))
```