# sf object is not properly overlaid on ggmap layer in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, r-sf, r-sp

I am trying to plot `sf` object over `ggmap` terrain layer in R. I am using the following code

```
library(ggmap)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

#Downloading data from DIVA GIS website
get_india_map <- function(cong=113) {
  tmp_file <- tempfile()
  tmp_dir  <- tempdir()
  zp <- sprintf("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/IND_adm.zip",cong)
  download.file(zp, tmp_file)
  unzip(zipfile = tmp_file, exdir = tmp_dir)
  fpath <- paste(tmp_dir)
  st_read(fpath, layer = "IND_adm2")
}
ind <- get_india_map(114)

#To view the attributes & first 3 attribute values of the data
ind[1:3,]

#Selecting specific districts
Gujarat <- ind %>% 
  filter(NAME_1=="Gujarat") %>%
  mutate(DISTRICT = as.character(NAME_2)) %>%
  select(DISTRICT)

#Added data to plot
aci <- tibble(DISTRICT=Gujarat$DISTRICT,
       aci=c(0.15,0.11,0.17,0.12,0.14,0.14,0.19,0.23,0.12,0.22,
                         0.07,0.11,0.07,0.13,0.03,0.07,0.06,0.04,0.05,0.04,
                         0.03,0.01,0.06,0.05,0.1))

Gujarat <- Gujarat %>% left_join(aci, by="DISTRICT")

#Plotting terrain layer using ggmap
vt <- get_map("India", zoom = 5, maptype = "terrain", source = "google")
ggmap(vt)

#Overlaying 'sf' layer
ggmap(vt) + 
  geom_sf(data=Gujarat,aes(fill=`aci`), inherit.aes=F, alpha=0.9) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")
```

which returns me

[image]

As you can see from the plot the `sf` layer is not overlaid properly on the `ggmap` terrain layer. How to properly overlay the `sf` layer on the `ggmap` terrain layer?

But When I am using `sp` object in place of `sf` object the polygon fits properly on `ggmap` like

```
library(sp)
# sf -> sp
Gujarat_sp <- as_Spatial(Gujarat) 

viet2<- fortify(Gujarat_sp)
ggmap(vt) + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), 
                         size=.2, color='black', data=viet2, alpha=0) + 
  theme_map() + coord_map()
```

[image]

But I don't know how to fill the `geom_polygon` according to `aci`?

Comment: For the `fill` you are supplying a discreet color scale to continuous data. There are [ways](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-expand-color-palette-with-ggplot-and-rcolorbrewer/) to force it to work, but easier to use a color scale designed for continuous data, e.g.  `scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral")`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have also tried that and it worked. But the main problem remains (`sf` object not properly overlaid on `ggmap` layer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem using `sp` package after taking help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22096787/how-keep-information-from-shapefile-after-fortify), [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178597/how-to-create-a-continuous-scale-with-distinct-custom-color-and-value-breaks-wit) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229969/specifying-the-colour-scale-for-maps-in-ggplot). The problem was that after applying `fortify` on the spatial data, only polygon information was there without the attribute data. So, I have merged the attribute data to the fortified polygon. Here is the complete code

```
library(ggmap)
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)
library(sp)

#Downloading data from DIVA GIS website
get_india_map <- function(cong=113) {
  tmp_file <- tempfile()
  tmp_dir  <- tempdir()
  zp <- sprintf("http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/adm/IND_adm.zip",cong)
  download.file(zp, tmp_file)
  unzip(zipfile = tmp_file, exdir = tmp_dir)
  fpath <- paste(tmp_dir)
  st_read(fpath, layer = "IND_adm2")
}
ind <- get_india_map(114)

#To view the attributes & first 3 attribute values of the data
ind[1:3,]
#To plot it
plot(ind["NAME_2"])

#Selecting specific districts
Gujarat <- ind %>% 
  filter(NAME_1=="Gujarat") %>%
  mutate(DISTRICT = as.character(NAME_2)) %>%
  select(DISTRICT)

#Creating some data
aci <- tibble(DISTRICT=Gujarat$DISTRICT,
       aci=c(0.15,0.11,0.17,0.12,0.14,0.14,0.19,0.23,0.12,0.22,
                         0.07,0.11,0.07,0.13,0.03,0.07,0.06,0.04,0.05,0.04,
                         0.03,0.01,0.06,0.05,0.1))

vt <- get_map("India", zoom = 5, maptype = "terrain", source = "google")
ggmap(vt)

# sf -> sp
Gujarat_sp <- as_Spatial(Gujarat) 

# fortify the shape file
viet2<- fortify(Gujarat_sp, region = "DISTRICT")

# merge data
map.df <- left_join(viet2, aci, by=c('id'='DISTRICT')) 

#Plotting
ggmap(vt) + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill = `aci`), 
                         size=.2, color='black', data=map.df, alpha=0.8) + 
  theme_map() + coord_map() + scale_fill_distiller(name = "ACI", palette = "Spectral")
```

[image]

To make discrete classes following code may be used

```
#For discrete classes
map.df$brks <- cut(map.df$aci, 
                   breaks=c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25), 
                   labels=c("0 - 0.05", "0.05 - 0.10", "0.10 - 0.15", 
                            "0.15 - 0.20", "0.20 - 0.25"))

# Mapping with the order of colour reversed 
ggmap(vt) + geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill = brks), 
                     size=.2, color='black', data=map.df, alpha=0.8) +
  theme_map() + coord_map() + 
  scale_fill_brewer(name="ACI", palette = "Spectral", direction = -1)
```

[image]