# Plotting to shapefile region with ggplot / ggmap

Tags: r, plot, mapping, gis

I have a shapefile showing the map of England with regions mapped on it:

```
England <- readOGR(dsn = "...")

England.fort <- fortify(England, region='regionID') 
England.fort <-England.fort[order(England.fort$order), ]
```

giving me England.fort:

```
England.fort
>long
>lat
>order
>hole
>piece
>id      #contains the region IDs
>group   #contains the region IDs
>Total   #I want to plot this
```

Shapefile from here: https://geoportal.statistics.gov.uk/Docs/Boundaries/Local_authority_district_(GB)_2014_Boundaries_(Generalised_Clipped).zip

I want to plot the regions showing the total number of people in each:

```
p <- ggplot(data=England.fort, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill="Total")) + 
     geom_polygon(colour='black', fill='white') + theme_bw()
```

But It gives me a blank map off England with all the regions white.

Comment: maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052544/convert-map-data-to-data-frame-using-fortify-ggplot2-for-spatial-objects-in-r

Comment: I tried the fortify command by it created a data frame with no reference back to the region IDs (LAD14D), so I couldn't link the totals to it

Comment: actually I think this link takes care of the issue you are mentioning!

Comment: Thanks, that's nearly got it. I've updated the question. I can't get the regions to plot...

Comment: actually I think I forgot to paste the link I wanted to send you https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles

Comment: p <- ggplot(data=England.fort)
      aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=percentage) + 
        geom_polygon(colour='black') + coord_equal() +
        scale_fill_brewer("Total")
Sorry about this, this isn't plotting

Comment: try to to remove colour='black' from geom_polygon() and there is "+" missing ggplot(data=England.fort) aes

Comment: p <- ggplot(data=England.fort, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=Total)) + 
        geom_polygon() + coord_equal() +
        scale_fill_brewer("Total")

Sorry about this, I now have: Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale . But Total is of type int

Comment: if you convert Total into a factor, does it fix your problem?

Comment: trying to plot it after converting to factr took 8gigs?! and crashed out

Comment: don't know what to say :)..but you could remove scale_fill_brewer("Total")  to test the rest of your code

Comment: that fixes it! Thanks.

Comment: you could try to post an answer for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ggplot(data=England.fort, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, Fill=Total)) + 
          geom_polygon() +
          theme_bw()
```

Does the trick. Thanks